Android build error: "Android resource linking failed"
* What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR: C:\\Users\\swecha\\AwesomeProject\\android\\app\\src\\main\\AndroidManifest.xml:12:7-24:18: AAPT: error: 'portraitnpx' is incompatible with attribute screenOrientation (attr) enum \[behind=3, fullSensor=10, fullUser=13, landscape=0, locked=14, nosensor=5, portrait=1, reverseLandscape=8, reversePortrait=9, sensor=4, sensorLandscape=6, sensorPortrait=7, unspecified=4294967295, user=2, userLandscape=11, userPortrait=12\].

* Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 10s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. \* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. \> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction \> Android resource linking failed ERROR: C:\\Users\\swecha\\AwesomeProject\\android\\app\\src\\main\\AndroidManifest.xml:12:7-24:18: AAPT: error: 'portraitnpx' is incompatible with attribute screenOrientation (attr) enum \[behind=3, fullSensor=10, fullUser=13, landscape=0, locked=14, nosensor=5, portrait=1, reverseLandscape=8, reversePortrait=9, sensor=4, sensorLandscape=6, sensorPortrait=7, unspecified=4294967295, user=2, userLandscape=11, userPortrait=12\]. \* Try: \> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. \> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. \> Run with --scan to get full insights. \> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 10s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

after entering ("npx react-native run-android") i should get it on virtual device but it is not coming

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Looks like there's a typo in the manifest file (AwesomeProject\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml)
Search for android:screenOrientation in the manifest file and change portraitnpx to portrait

TQ bro, For answering my question . i am not getting this error after installing git and running "npm run android" instead of "npx react-native run-android". but tq for responding.
